# Qual a melhor forma de usar templates no Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, parser

Estou utilizando a versão 3 do codeigniter e inserindo o conceito de templates através da biblioteca PARSER, conforme a propria documentação do CI

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/parser.html

Acontece que na versão 2 eu utiliza um modelo de layout atraves de um Hook, conforme este exemplo:

http://flaviosilveira.com/2010/habilitando-layouts-no-codeigniter-template-engine-2/

Neste ultimo a utilização era mais simples pois no Hook eu ja tinha a definicao de qual parte do bloco iria o o conteudo da minha view, ou seja fazendo o includes das partes estaticas, como cabecalho, e rodape, mudando apenas o corpo da view.

Ja no caso no parser eu ainda nao consegui entender como fazer essas chamadas dos includes estaticos de forma mais usual.

Seria algo como:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

       public function index() {     
            $data = array(
                       'blog_title' => 'My Blog Title',
                        'title' => 'My Title'
                     );
            $row['nome'] = $this->session->userdata('nome');
            $this->parser->parse('templates/cabecalho', $row);
            $this->load->view('welcome_message');
            $this->parser->parse('templates/rodape');
        }
}
```

Seria este o melhor modelo para trabalhar com layouts utilizando o PARSER?

Comment: A melhor forma seria que o template engine fornecesse algo mecanismo para 'montar' o layout. O código mostrado na pergunta parece boilerplate imagine repetir as chamadas `parse(), view(), parse()` (a grosso modo são 3 includes em uma ordem rigida) para todas as páginas, imagine se tivesse um menu lateral ai seriam 4 arquivos chamados o tempo todo, é possíve criar um método para centrar a montagem.

Comment: A ideia seria ter um arquivo 'principal' que teria 3 'sessões', cabeçalho, miolo e rodapé, no controller vc só passaria o miolo com os dados. Dá pra fazer isso sem framework de uma olhada como o laravel faz é bacana.

Comment: Exatamente isso, a repetição do codigo seria algo extremamente cansativo e nem um pouco usual. O Blade do laravel eu acho excelente, e o hook que eu usava na versao anterior se aproxima muito disso. No caso desenvolvendo uma classe pra fazer essa interacao entre as chamadas dos templates e a inserção dos conteudos.

Comment: Depois vou dar uma olhada nesse hook.

Comment: Sim, embora eu gostaria de adotar o parser no CI3, e me aproximar um pouco do balde, ainda vejo o parser como não muito intuitivo, me obrigado a repetir codigos, ou utilizar a mesma logica desde hook. De qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Particularmente eu gosto de usar dessa forma:

```
public function _site($view) {

    $this->load->vars($this->dados);
    $this->load->view('view_topo');      
    if (is_array($view)) {
        foreach ($view as $valor) {
           $this->load->view($valor);
        }
    } else {
        $this->load->view($view);
    }     
    $this->load->view('view_rodape');       
}
```

Neste caso, eu chamo no controller:

```
    $dados['vantagems'] = $this->model_vantagem->get_vantagem_lista();
    $this->load->vars($dados); // Load nas variaveis que eu preciso usar na view
    $this->_site(array('view_vantagem'));
```

Talvez lhe ajude também!

Comment: Andre, no caso vc implementou uma classe com esse primeiro e trecho e ao extender no seu controller vc chama o metodo _site($view). Agora a variavel dados, voce pode enviar ela a view atraves de um $this->_site(array('view_vantagem'), $dados)???

Comment: Exatamente, criei uma classe chamada my_controller, que fiz extends MX_Controller, pra conseguir controlar melhor o site, assim eu chamo as views corretamente já... se eu for chamar apenas uma view, sem topo ou rodape, só chamo $this->load->view("view");

Comment: Sim, mais ou menos como o hook que mencionei, no entanto a parte que voce coloca $this->load->vars($this->dados), nunca vai ser usada no metodo _site, seria preciso passar ele como paramentro tbm